# Magento2 Creating admin route causes exception

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, router

I've setup a `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` for my module with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <router name="admin">
        <route id="blog" frontName="blog">
            <module name="Vendor_Blog" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Which causes the following error in `var/report` whenever I try to access the admin panel;

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /vagrant/public/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php on line 51"`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not test properly yet. But your admin xml is wrong.

1) Missing Schema Validation:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    ......
</config>
```

2) Element `router`, attribute `name`: The attribute `name` is not allowed.

`<router name="admin">` => need to change to `<router id="admin">`.

So, your route should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd>
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="blog" frontName="blog">
            <module name="Vendor_Blog" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: I believe the `<router id="admin">` was throwing the error. Thanks!